overloading var_export() to customize
I've a persistent library that should store objects in a database. So var_export() should store the type, pk, and db-version only. At the reverse it should recreated the object from the database using the key. In other words:
class Person
{
  use PersistTrait; // $id, $store, __get, __set

  protected string $name;
  protected string $website;

  public function __construct(string $id)
  {
    // connect to db
    // retrieve object content by $id
  }
  public static function __set_state($array_with_only_id): Person
  {
    // check version
    return new self( $array_with_only_id['id'] ); // exception when not found etc.
  } 
}

$person = new \Person();
$person->name = 'ElePHPant ElePHPantsdotter';
$person->website = 'https://php.net/elephpant.php';
$person->store();

$c = var_export($person);
// $c should only contain "
Person::__set_state(
  [
    'id'=>'pk-value-of-person',
    'version'=>'db-version'
  ]
);

Is this possible?

Why var_export()? __serialize()/__unserialize() already provides this functionality.

Note also, your constructor is spelled wrong, and if it were spelled correctly, you'd have a required argument that you don't pass when you instantiate. You've also got protected attributes that you're trying to directly manipulate outside the class.

As noted, the built-in serialize functions can handle this for you, and you can elevate those to one or more traits (or include it with your existing trait even): https://3v4l.org/tQ21K

@AlexHowansky Serializable::serialize()and Serializable::unserialize() would be different use cases, wouldn't they? I'm not sure why __serialize()/__unserialize() exist. But yes, var_export() probably is concepted for a specific use case I'm not aiming here.

@AlexHowansky setting/getting protected properties is handled by the trait. as they indicate a 'dirty' instance.

The var_export() aims one very specific use case: convert a construct (array, object) in a language specific string form that can be used to recreate the object. Much like Serializable::serialize() and Serializable::unserialize() combo but with the class type included. It was not meant to be used in a more generic use case.
